# how to convert a python expression to a java expression?

Tags: java, python, boolean, transform

I have the following expression in python:

```
if 0.85 < 0.81 / 0.83 < 1.15 :
    //do something
```

When I put this in python there is no problem and it returns a boolean (true) but I don't understand what '/' is? because it looks like your dividing two booleans. What does this expression evaluation to in java?

Comment: This document has an exact answer to your question: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: BTW, the code you posted is most defiitely not Python, so please fix it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the doc carefully. `/` is the more binding operator, so @ZWiki was correct. There are effectively parens around the division operation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Was going to say, the table is low-to-high binding. Division is higher precedence.

Comment: @cricket_007. Yeah, sorry about that, I feel like a dumbass.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, python's peephole optimizer compiles this down to `if (true)` :)

Answer (score 5):

In java,

```
if (0.85 < 0.81 / 0.83 &&  0.81 / 0.83 < 1.15) {
    //do something
}

// A better solution as mentioned by @Makoto
float f = 0.81/0.83
if (0.85<f &&  f< 1.15) {
    //do something
}
```

---

In Python, all comparison operations have the same priority. It can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y < z` is equivalent to `x < y and y < z`. Refer to [Python documentation: Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) for the detailed description.

Comment: Truth be told, you only want to do that division once, so I'd recommend putting it in a separate variable.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use `and`(&&) to get a `True` :

```
if (0.85 < 0.81 / 0.83 && 0.81 / 0.83 < 1.15) {
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Going to the docs, the answer to your question is literally spelled out in these two sections (both on the same page):

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

The first section gives a table that states that `/` has higher precedence than `<`, so your expression is effectively `0.85 < (0.81 / 0.83) < 1.15`, or `0.85 < 0.9759036144578315 < 1.15`.

The second section states:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

This means that your statement translates exactly as

```
double x = 0.81 / 0.83;
if(0.85 < x && x < 1.15) {
    // ...
}
```

The key here is that with comparison chaining, each expression is only evaluated once. In this case that means computing the division only once. Of course the Java compiler would probably have optimized that out for you anyway.